# My visual studio code integrated terminal is ugly how to change it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

[Visual Studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ct1k.png)

I want to change the purple background. Whenever I run the program, it highlights the text and gives purple background.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your user settings and edit the `terminal.foreground` and `terminal.background` of `workbench.colorCustomizations` in `settings.json`

1. Open user settings (ctrl + ,)
2. Choose ***Workbench*** from the sidebar or search for it.
3. Select ***Edit in settings.json***
4. Paste the below json snippet into the file and save.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations" : {
    "terminal.foreground" : "#00FD61",
    "terminal.background" : "#383737"
}
```

You may also get more granular control over your terminal colors with this snippet.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.background":"#282C34",
        "terminal.foreground":"#CAE0AC",
        "terminal.ansiBlack":"#282C34",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#7FB323",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#00AFEF",
        "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#56B6C2",
        "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#AAD76F",
        "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#CEE066",
        "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#FC7474",
        "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#DCE4DF",
        "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#22F901",
        "terminal.ansiCyan":"#70E8F8",
        "terminal.ansiGreen":"#6A8854",
        "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#C678DD",
        "terminal.ansiRed":"#FB4242",
        "terminal.ansiWhite":"#DCDFE4",
        "terminal.ansiYellow":"#E5C07B"
  }
```